# Embed images in html using base64 encoding

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, base64

I am trying to embed an image in my emails.

```
<%= image_tag("data:image/png;base64,base64-encoded string", alt:"Facebook") %>
```

Not throwing any error of image not found. But image is also not coming.

Comment: well, this syntax should work. Post the actual data.

Comment: Actual data in the sense actual base64 encoded string.

Comment: yep, the actual string. Or first test if the image display on a web page, not email. If it does, then the problem is elsewhere, not in the image_tag.

Comment: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHEAAABxCAMAAADVoLziAAAAk1BMVEXkAEbkAUfkAkfkA0jkBEnl
CEzlCU3lCk3lC07mD1HmEFLmEVLmE1TmFFXnG1roJGDoJWHoJmLpL2jqNWzqNm3rQHTrQXXrRnns
SXvtWIbuXInuX4vvZ5HvaJHwc5nwdJrwdZvygqTyg6X0lLH0mLT3t8v4vtD60d772uT85Ov96O79
6e/+8fX+9fj+9/n++fv///+Jil3GAAAA0ElEQVRo3u3WNxbCQBAE0cVoQXjvvffM/U9HJFgiAlAH
vKoL/KxnnCMiIiIi+teyUalSjotRTqLl26uzPTu2UvdGV3urmzJYO5lJxa6ZVmyaWCxe1OLaxGJs
anEmFw9q0YfOfd4sFbz33mfTExsBeKsq9rQTiEPJgg8CMZaIo0DMSMRxIDpERESXiZIWgRi9+rlY
tQ/Jxb1c3MjFqVzsycW6XIzlYk4tXpxa3MrFZRrDmjQJ/5wkrhUiIiIiIiIiIiIi4g/r7145IiIi
IiL6sgdumcGzw60e4wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

Comment: This works in normal rails email preview but not in actual gmail.

Comment: Yeah it works in normal webapge.